# Failed to attach the USB device Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth USB Host Controller

Tags: macos, bluetooth, virtualbox

I am unable to pass through the host Bluetooth USB through my Kali. I am using VirtualBox on Mac Mojave. When I select it through 'Device', I get the above error

> [Failed to attach the USB device Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth USB Host Controller [0168] to the virtual machine].
>
> Could not find USB with uuid {xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx}
>
> Callee RC: NE_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)

I have tried almost everything posted in StackOverflow under similar questions/issues, but could not resolve the issue.

Also, I am noticing a strange behavior, when I am passing through my Logitech USB Optical Mouse, it stops responding, and when I uncheck it again under 'Device', it starts to respond, meaning I am able to use the mouse.

Little bit more context- I noticed this issue, after I upgraded to Mac Mojave from Sierra, if this helps. Earlier it was working without any issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1 - Open the Finder;
2 - Go to options menu: 'Go ->  Go to Folder...';
3 - Write the '/Library/Preferences';
4 - Remove the file called 'com.apple.Bluetooth.plist';
5 - Restart the macOS.

That way it is working for me.